# IPython Notebooks - how to get INLINE command line option to work for images?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, inline, jupyter-notebook, simplecv

I'm using the SimpleCV framework with IPython notebooks under Windows Vista.

I can't get result images to be shown within the body of the notebook, they just appear in a separate pop-out window.

I'm running a batch file to fire up IPyhton and have tried the following with no success:

```
 ipython notebook --pylab inline


 ipython notebook --pylab=inline
```

SmartCV1.3 "Developer"
IPython 0.13.2
Windows Vista/Chrome 26

Comment: What happens when you run `%pylab inline` as the first command in IPython?

Comment: Thanks Filmor, after 20 hours of install hell trying to get this all to hang together I'm grateful for any assistance. Initially I got 'module does not exist' import error. Fixed that by clean installing matlibplot, which seems to be working great now and producing beautiful inline plots.

However I still have the original problem with displaying my (SimpleCV related) images inline as per my original question.

Comment: would [this tutorial](http://www.pyvideo.org/video/1796/simplecv-computer-vision-using-python) from last pycon help ?

Comment: Kat has told me I need to be using the developer version for this feature to work-which I've installed to no avail.  Any assistance appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with SimpleCV but do Matplotlob figures show inline or do they pop out as well? Improper configuration of the notebook will cause inline matplotlib figures to pop out and block

Answer (score 0):

I would try to run from the develop branch versus the super pack, the pylab pass-through was not present in the 1.3 release (which is getting rather long in the tooth). Officially we don't support Windows Vista, and we don't test on it regularly since most of the core devs use OSX and Linux. We're actively looking for Windows developers to help us with testing on Windows (if you're interested). I suggest you try the [simplecv help forum](http://help.simplecv.org).

Comment: oh, I forgot to add, try using "simplecv notebook --pylab=inline" that might be your problem.